# Calling Java methods from C without starting the JVM from C

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, jnienv

I am looking for a tutorial for how to call Java methods from C using JNI. In all the tutorials that I've found so far, the examples show how to first create a JVM from C.

My application starts from Java and uses JNI to call some C functions. I now need to call some Java functions from C and I don't want to start the JVM from C.

Is it possible, for instance, to create a "native" method implemented in C, and to use it in order to save the `JNIEnv` pointer, and then to reuse it, instead of creating a new JVM instance from C, in order to call Java methods?

Is there an example for it?

---

**EDIT:**

**Whoever reads this thread should be careful!** Only use the `JNIEnv*` instance that comes from the current JNI call! Do not save and reuse any `JNIEnv*` pointer that you got before, if you don't want your program to crash.

**Using and old saved pointer, could in the best scenario crash your application.** In worse scenarios, it can cause low-level inconsistency problems that are very hard to debug and understand

**No `JNIEnv*` instance should be cached, since if your program starts from Java, then your C code will anyway be able to execute only as a native java method, that its C implementation always gets a relevant `JNIEnv*` instance**. This is the only instance that you should use until your native method returns, and not any old saved instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As JJF stated, this is definitely possible!  I'll show an example below, assuming you already know how to call Java methods from C, but without having to create a JVM!

First, we have a Java class `test.Test.java` that calls the native method `methodA`:

```
package test;

public class Test {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("test");
    }

    private native void methodA();

    public static void methodB() {
        System.out.println("Java: Method B has executed!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().methodA();
    }
}
```

Next, we have the header file created by `javah` or `javac -h`:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class test_Test */

#ifndef _Included_test_Test
#define _Included_test_Test
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     test_Test
 * Method:    methodA
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_test_Test_methodA
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Below is the C file which holds the native method `methodA`:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test_Test.h"


void callMethodB(JNIEnv *env);

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_test_Test_methodA(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {
    printf("C: Method A executed!\n"); fflush(stdout);
    callMethodB(env);
    return;
}

void callMethodB(JNIEnv *env) {
    jclass testClass = (*env) -> FindClass(env, "test/Test");
    jmethodID methodB = (*env) -> GetStaticMethodID(env, testClass, "methodB", "()V");
    (*env) -> CallStaticVoidMethod(env, testClass, methodB, NULL);
    return;
}
```

The output of this program is:

> C: Method A executed!
>
> Java: Method B has executed!

Remember to create a `test.dll` file with your preferred GNU compiler.

Comment: caching the env pointer is usually not a good idea, however, because it is not reusable across threads.

Comment: Thanks @user2543253, I've just learned it in the (very) hard way

Comment: Could you please refine you answer, @Jacob ? It is important to only use the `JNIEnv*` instance you get in a specific call, else you'd mix threads and will not likely to find out fast what happened'

Comment: And since you shouldn't cache the `JNIEnv*` there's no longer any need for the global variable; just pass the `JNIEnv*` as an argument to any function that needs it.

Comment: I've just removed the JNIEnv pointer caching thing and approved the answer. The JNIEnv pointer is only valid for the context in which the native method has been called, therefore caching it may be a pretty bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of creating a new Java VM (which isn't possible anyway when the current process already has one) you can get the existing Java VM with `JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs). Use `AttachCurrentThread` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#AttachCurrentThread) to get an env pointer.

This will also work in a multithreaded environment, while passing env pointers around will only work in a single thread.

Comment: If the shared library implements a `JNI_OnLoad` function it's also possible to get the `JavaVM*` that way. While `JNIEnv*`s shouldn't be cached, the `JavaVM*` is safe to cache.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an experimental solution that may not work. It works by using the JNIEnv_ struct rather than creating a JNIEnv object, which relieves the need to create a Java Virtual Machine. It can only call JNI native images, not jar files.

```cpp
#include <jni.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    JNIEnv_ *jni;
    jclass mainClass = jni->FindClass("net/minecraft/client/main/Main");
    jmethodID constructor = jni->GetStaticMethodID(mainClass, "Main", "()V");
    jni->CallStaticVoidMethod(mainClass, constructor);
    return 0;
}
```